# Maintain scroll position when opening jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using Jquery UI Dialog to display a popup box

I have a page with a grid on. Each row has an icon to open a dialog box

If there are lots of rows and you need to scroll down and click a row at the bottom, then when the dialog box opens it also scrolls the page to the top again

Is there any way to prevent this happening?

I just want the dialog box to be opened and the scroll position of the page to be maintained

```
$('#AmendLineDialogBox').dialog({
            autoOpen: true,
            modal: true,
            closeOnEscape: true,
            buttons:
                {
                    'Ok': function () {
// ...snip
                            $(this).dialog("close");                  
                    },
                    'Cancel': function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                },
            position: 'center',
            title: 'Amendment'
        });
```

Comment: try adding "return false;" after calling this dialog.

Comment: The icon which opens the dialog, is it wrapped in `<a>`?

Comment: `#AmendLineDialogBox` whose id is this icon or <a>?

Comment: @Jai yes, it's an img wrapped in an anchor

Comment: @Jai AmendLineDialogBox is the div whose content is displayed in the dialog.

Comment: @Davor return false has no effect

Comment: somehow i think that anchor is problem: <a href="#" onclick="$(#id).dialog('open'); return false;">open dialog</a> or replace it with div or span...

Answer (score 1):

You can do chaining like this:

```
$('#AmendLineDialogBox').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault(); //<--------------^-------prevent the default behaviour
}).dialog({
        autoOpen: true,
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        buttons:
            {
                'Ok': function () {
 // ...snip
                        $(this).dialog("close");                  
                },
                'Cancel': function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            },
        position: 'center',
        title: 'Amendment'
    });
```